# How to constantly update an integer

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to update my int *hp* inside of an enemy's class and can't seem to update it correctly. I've made a separate method that tried to redefine the variable to subtract the damage the player has done but that hasn't worked. I call for it in the method used for combat and the integer is still either being redefined to 12 or for the variable to spit out random numbers.

```java
public static int hp(){

        hp = 12;

        return hp;
    } 
public void damaging() {

        hp -= Combat.damage();

    }
```

Comment: how is `hp` defined?

Comment: The `hp()` function will always reset the `hp` variable to `12`. Is that what you wanted? Try to create a [mcve].

Comment: Well of course it is reassigned to 12, because you do that ... in that method ... literally. When to don't want that, then don't do it. Easy as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `hp()` redefines the variable `hp` to be equal to 12 every time it is called. Try to define `hp` at a higher context, such as a global or member variable.
Try something like this:

```
hp = 12;
public static int hp() {
        return hp;
}

public void damaging() {
        hp -= Combat.damage();
}
```

This way your `hp` variable is defined only once at code start or at class declaration.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Sorry I'm new to Java

Comment: Short answer, take your variable out of any method, that should give you a global or a class member variable.

Comment: Could you please give me an example? Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer to include the example you want.

Comment: It can't be, the only way it gets redefined is that you (accidentally) reexecute that part of the code.

Comment: You're right I forgot to delete the hp inside of the hp method